# System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration does not contain a definition for 'Configure

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In global asax cs file i have this line:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

which causes this error.

I have tried as suggested on other forums:

1. Open the Package Manager Console for the project with the error.
2. Type in Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost and hit Enter
3. Rebuild your project and all should be right with the world (or at least right with your project)

The output was:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.2.2 && < 5.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 5.2.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 6.0.4)'.
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.2.2' already installed.
SM.EORD.Web already has a reference to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.2.2'.
```

and error is still there. What could be wrong?

br, Simon

Answer (score 3):

After hours of investigating i have found out that after I have installed ASP.NET Web API 2.2, the reference path of all dlls was from some old Web API - it didn't take the new ones.
The new dlls has been installed in packages folder, while the old one were in bin folder inside project.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update your references as well next time try upgrading from the package manager console you can update all or just specify the package name. Update package will upgrade vs installing a new package and you have manually go update your references.

Update-Package

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I renamed the Namespace of my project, and I did not know I needed to manually edit the namespaces section of the Views\Web.Config to match my new namespace.